# Issue in searching & downloading Sentinel-5P data within proxy environment

Tags: python, sentinel-5p

I am trying to download sentinel-5p data by using the following code:

```
from sentinel5dl import search, download

result = search(
        polygon='POLYGON((7.8 49.3,13.4 49.3,13.4 52.8,7.8 52.8,7.8 49.3))',
        begin_ts='2019-09-01T00:00:00.000Z',
        end_ts='2019-09-17T23:59:59.999Z',
        product='L2__CO____',
        processing_level='L2',
        processing_mode='Offline')

# Download found products to the local folder
download(result.get('products'))
```

After running the above code I am getting the following error:
`error: (4, "Unsupported proxy 'https://user:user@123@172.xx.xx.xx:8080', libcurl is built without the HTTPS-proxy support.")`

With the same proxy settings I am able to download Sentinel 1 & 2 data using sentinelsat python library. But when i am using this library I am getting the above error.

Please help me in how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of one of your dependencies and not related to the `sentinelsat` or `sentinel5dl` libraries.

The way you can attempt to solve this is by installing a version of `libcurl` on your system that supports HTTPS-proxies. `libcurl` is easiest updated by installing a newer version of `curl` to your system. https://curl.se/download.html

If you are on a windows system you might want to look at installing it using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) as getting `libcurl` to play nice can be tricky on non-UNIX systems.